# Prove this map is dominant

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I sat an exam today on elementary algebraic geometry, which is now finished (it was a morning exam), and have been allowed to take the paper home (to be clear, the exam is now *over*). I've been wrestling with one of the questions all day but can't make any sense of it:

> Suppose that $P,Q,R \in \mathbb{K}[x,z]$ are homogeneous, with $\deg P
>  = d \gt 0, \; \deg R = d -1, \; \deg Q = d+1$, and that $P^2 + QR \neq 0$.
>
> Define a rational map $\psi: \mathbb{P}^2 \dashrightarrow
>  \mathbb{P}^2$ by
>
> $\psi((x:y:z)) = (x(yR(x,z) - P(x,z)):yP(x,z) + Q(x,z):z(yR(x,z) - P(x,z)))$.
>
> By considering $\psi \circ \psi$, or otherwise, show that $\psi$ is
>   dominant.

Our definition of dominant: For $X$ and $Y$ projective algebraic sets, $\psi:X \dashrightarrow Y$ is dominant if there does not exist a projective algebraic set $W \subsetneq Y$ such that $\psi(p) \in W$ for every $p$ where $\psi$ is defined.

We have a lemma which is an alternative criterion for dominance, which says that $\psi$ is dominant if there exists a projective algebraic set $Z \subsetneq Y$ such that every $q \in Z^c$ can be written as $\psi(p)$ for some $p$ in $X$.

I can't see how to use either of these. I've tried composing $\psi$ with itself, and the expression I get is an awful mess. Does anyone have any clever ideas?

Comment: Can you please check the parentheses?

Comment: They were wrong - not sure how I didn't spot that. Now corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U = \{ yR-P \ne 0\} \cap \{P^2+QR \ne 0\} \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2 $. Note that $\psi$ is a morphism on $U$. Let $p=[x:y:z] \in U$. Then $\psi(p) = (x: \frac{yP+Q}{yR-P}: z)$.

Observe that $\psi(p) \in U$, since if $\frac{yP+Q}{yR-P} R - P = 0$, then $QR + P^2 = 0$. So it follows that $\psi(U) \subseteq U$.

Now observe that we have $\psi \circ \psi (p) = \psi(x: \frac{yP+Q}{yR-P}: z) = (x: \frac{ \frac{yP+Q}{yR-P}P + Q}{\frac{yP+Q}{yR-P}R-P}: z) = (x:y:z) $. So it follows that $\psi: U \rightarrow U$ is an isomorphism.

This implies that the image of $\psi$ (as a rational map, where its domain may be larger than $U$) contains the open subset $U$. But this implies that the image of $\psi$ is dense (since $U$ is dense as it is an open subset of $\mathbb{P}^2$), hence dominant.